# Use lombok with @XmlElement

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling, lombok

How can I use Lombok in conjunction with my `@XmlElement` tags so that I can unmarshall the object?

I have about 20 properties, so I'm looking to not write an explicit getter and setter for each with the `XmlElement` tags on the setters.

Comment: Just add @Data annotation for the class. The getter and setter will not be needed. Also if you are using some IDE, you will need a plugin to use Lombok.

Comment: Is there any problem left now? The question is not clear to me.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This gets the job done:

```
@Data
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)      // UPDATE: Need this or else exception
public class Data {
    @XmlElement(name = "test")
    public double testData;
}
```

Comment: I have the "The annotation @XmlElement is disallowed for this location" message. Do you know anything about ?

Comment: solved... we need to put this peace of code:   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

Comment: However, I have a customize xml request, so I can't read the nested value... Only can read the values when it is inside the root tag and no when it is inside a customized xml tag :( I have troubles

Comment: Does the field really need to be public, or can I set it to private?