# Unmarshall xml - the main class get null

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have xml i need to unmarshall:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE nitexp SYSTEM "http://www.nitml.org/nitexp/1.0/nitexp.dtd" [<!ENTITY % nitcml SYSTEM "http://www.nitml.org/nitcml/1.0/nitcml.dtd" > %nitcml;]>
    <nitexp xmlns="http://www.nitml.org/nitexp/1.0">
    <item type="sasa">
    <nd>nitl20043581</nd>
    <source>
    <name>name</name>
    <issue>
    <publicdate>20200210</publicdate>
    <page>32</page>
    <column></column>
    </issue>
    </source>
    <title>Immof inanz </title>
    <author>hshsa</author>
    <annotation>
    <nitcml xmlns="http://www.nitml.org/nitcml/1.0">
    </nitcml>
    </annotation>
    <content>
    <nitcml xmlns="http://www.nitml.org/nitcml/1.0">
    <body><p><l>dsadasdasd</l><l>dasdasd</l><l> dasdas</l><l></l></p></body>
    </nitcml>
    </content>
    <nmms><importdate>20200210</importdate>
    <topic code="np01"/>
    <mark> </mark>
    <useraction></useraction>
    <weight></weight>
    <group></group><attachments></attachments><note>
    <nitcml xmlns="http://www.nitml.org/nitcml/1.0"></nitcml></note>
    <translation><nitcml xmlns="http://www.nitml.org/nitcml/1.0"></nitcml>
    </translation>
    <field>
    <value>ni</value>
    <value>20a04</value>
    <value>358d1</value>
    </field>
    </nmms>
    </item>
    </nitexp>
```

I can easilly marshall it, but when i try on the other side i get null Item. My main class is:

```
  @Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@ToString
@XmlRootElement(name = "nitexp", namespace="http://www.nitml.org/nitexp/1.0")
public class Article {

    private Item item = Item.builder().build();

    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    public ArticleItem getItem() {
        return item;
    }

}
```

then

```
  @Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@ToString
@XmlType(propOrder={"type","nitoid","source","title","author","annotation","content","nmms"})
public class ArticleItem {

    private String type;
    private String nitoid;
    private ArticleSource source = new ArticleSource();
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String annotation;
    private String content;
    private String nmms;


    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
```

...and so on..

I work with Java 12, i have jaxb-api and glassfish.jaxb in my pom dependencies. I tried to put @XMLElement annotations on getters and setters. I tried to put XMLRootElement annotation on each nested class but with no luck. I also tried not to use @Builder, and not to initialize class objects. I even tried to modify my xml and cut the second row but it is not the problem. Now I do not even know what can I do different, what to change and how to examine where can be possible problem.
I will be gratefull for any suggestions, ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried approach described in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47040399/2792888 ?

Comment: yes, not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following setup worked for me:

Article class:

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "nitexp", namespace="http://www.nitml.org/nitexp/1.0")
public class Article {

    @XmlElement(name = "item", namespace="http://www.nitml.org/nitexp/1.0")
    private ArticleItem  item;

}
```

ArticleItem  class:

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "item", namespace="http://www.nitml.org/nitexp/1.0")
public class ArticleItem {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String type;

    @XmlElement(name = "nd", namespace="http://www.nitml.org/nitexp/1.0")
    private String nitoid;

    @XmlElement(name = "title", namespace="http://www.nitml.org/nitexp/1.0")
    private String title;

    @XmlElement(name = "author", namespace="http://www.nitml.org/nitexp/1.0")
    private String author;

}
```

Unmarshalling process:

```
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Article.class).createUnmarshaller();
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(data);
    Object obj = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(reader));
    System.out.println(obj);
```

Output:

```
Article(item=ArticleItem(type=sasa, nitoid=nitl20043581, title=Immof inanz , author=hshsa))
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great! Adding >> namespace="http://www.nitml.org/nitexp/1.0"<< did the job. It works also with other Lombok annotations.